# HTML Entity validation error

Tags: html

Could anyone tell me why I keep receiving the error for the below code:

```
<div class="sidebox-header-left">
<h3 class="rightBoxHeading" id="ezpagesHeading">Advertisement</h3>
    <br/>
<a href="http://www.test.com/tread.php?s=000&v=0&q=000&r=000&clickref=test.com"><img src="http://www.test.com/tshow.php?s=000&v=000&q=000&r=000" border="0"></a>            </div>
    <div id="ezpagesContent" class="sideBoxContent">
</div>
    </div>
```

I'm using HTML 4.01 Transitional, however i keep getting the following errors for the above code:

> Warning Line 298, Column 56: reference to external entity in attribute value
>   …`p://www.test.com/tread.php?s=000&v=000&q=000&r=000&clickref=test.com`
>
> This is generally the sign of an ampersand that was not properly escaped for inclusion in an attribute, in a href for example. You will need to escape all instances of '`&`' into '`&amp;`'.

Comment: Do what the warning says: escape your URL! http://www.test.com/tread.php?s=000&amp;v=0...

Comment: `<br/>` means "A line break followed by a `>`" in HTML 4. You aren't writing XHTML, don't use XML self-closing tag syntax. Get rid of the `/`.

Answer (score 0):

See this information from the validator (that you included in your question)?

> You will need to escape all instances of '`&`' into '`&amp;`'.

Do that.

```
<a href="http://www.test.com/tread.php?s=000&amp;v=0&amp;q=000&amp;r=000&amp;clickref=test.com">
```

Answer (score 0):

`&` should be `&amp;` in the URL if you care about validation.